# Производные предлоги: состав слов

Tags: предлоги, окончания, морфемика, морфемный-разбор

У производных предлогов есть окончания или нет? Например, "**в течение** месяца". Здесь "**е**" — это окончание или суффикс?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, предлоги не разбираются по составу https://studwork.org/russkiy-yazyk/1431745-imeyut-li-okonchanie-proizvodnye-predlogi-naprimer-v-techenie-mesyaca-e-eto-okonchanie

Comment: У меня ссылка не открывается, а вот решение не очень понятно. Все производные предлоги не разбираются по составу? А почему?  Вот у Литневской немного другая информация: непроизводными считаются предлоги, полностью утратившие смысловые связи с исходным словом. Но в данном случае мне эти связи не кажутся утраченными, есть понятие "течение времени". Поэтому можно считать, что Е – это суффикс, а не окончание (у предлогов одна падежная форма), как вы думаете? Таким образом, некоторые предлоги разбираются, а другие нет. У вас есть какой-нибудь авторитетный источник по этой теме (учебник, статья)?